# Apple Push Services created instead of Apple Production iOS Push Services

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to create a certificate for Production iOS Push Services.
Instead I get an ***Apple Push Services***.
How can I create a dedicated ***Apple Production iOS Push Services*** certificate?

The top certificate is what I used to get. The bottom one is what I now get.

[image]

I use Pusher application to test my push notifications certificate and it cannot read the p12 of the new Apple Push Services.

Comment: Do you need APNS to send push notification right?

Comment: Do you need. certificate for code sign or you are looking for SSL certificate ex. .p12,pem ?

Comment: SSL - the one that my server uses to send the push notifications

Comment: Same problem for me, All of my previous certificates are working, But with new certificates I'm getting error like "You have selected the Production server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Production certificate! Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!" (Server team is using Pushsharp to send notification).

Comment: @godmoney have you found the solution to this problem? I'm having a similar problem but I use PubNub push service.

Comment: Not yet unfortunatly

Comment: @godmonkey i too facing same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 42):

Apple have changed the name of the certificate that is issued.  You can now use the same certificate for both development and production.  While you can still request a development only certificate you can no longer request a production only certificate.

Since the purpose of the certificate is no longer production only Apple has changed the common name to Apple Push Services.  The functionality of the certificate is not affected.

Unfortunately services that validate the CN of the certificate may reject this new name.  There is nothing you can do about this until the service updates its verification code.  For example, Parse.com had this issue a few days ago but their verification code has now been updated and they will now accept the new certificate name.

Comment: Same problem for me, All of my previous certificates are working, But with new certificates I'm getting error like "You have selected the Production server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Production certificate! Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!"  (Server team is using Pushsharp to send notification)..

Comment: what's "CN"? sorry maybe I have lost some knowledge.

Comment: The common name that is embedded in the certificate.

Comment: @sivakrishna, have you find a solution for PushSharp?

Comment: @Hemang No, my service team is unable to edit/change any thing on those classes, for your reference    https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/pull/586

Comment: @sivakrishna, alright, thanks! Yes, I have seen your comments on that thread as well.

Comment: @Hemang It seems they have to change the files..., let me know if you find any solution...

Comment: @sivakrishna, no, not yet. I'm looking for a solution from last year :D

Comment: And it is called `Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)`

Comment: Then I could delete the certificate type `APNs Development iOS` or is it still required?

Answer (score 9):

Apple Change Apple Production IOS Push Services cert name to Apple Push Services
if you used pushsharp , you need go to github https://github.com/v-tsymbalistyi/PushSharp
download zip and used visual studio recombile
because the code change 
if (production && !subjectName.Contains("Apple Production IOS Push Services") && !subjectName.Contains("Apple Push Services"))
                    throw new ArgumentException("You have selected the Production server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Production certificate!  Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!");

```
            if (!production && !subjectName.Contains("Apple Development IOS Push Services") && !subjectName.Contains("Pass Type ID"))
                    throw new ArgumentException("You have selected the Development/Sandbox (Not production) server, yet your Certificate does not appear to be the Development/Sandbox certificate!  Please check to ensure you have the correct certificate!");
```

and you just copy PushSharp.Apple.dll to server 
then everything OK

Comment: Additionally, try the 3.0 series of PushSharp where this is fixed and generally works better anyway :)

Comment: Do we need to remove line which throws exception?

Comment: @Redth, 3.0 is still in beta, Also getting error as "Unable to find version '3.0.0-beta29' of package 'PushSharp'." while trying to install

Comment: @Redth can you please check that: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602663/pushsharp-2-fires-an-exception-while-sending-notification-to-apple-ios

Answer (score 4):

1. Login Apple Developer Account.
2. In Member Center -> click  Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
3. Choose IOS apps
4. In Certificates -> click add new(+)
5. There you can see Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox) [for development] and Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)
6. To click on continue , choose Appid(bundle id)
7. Need to continue. This have the demo to generate csr
8. Add CSR file
9. Then it generate APNs. Put the name for it.

Note:
    You can generate APNS for Development through Apple Push Notification service SSL and Production for Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production).

[image]

Comment: When I generate Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) then Apple Push Services is created instead of Apple Production iOS Push Services

Comment: Can you send the screen shot of it. I think both are same . you don't worry of it. That is production APNS. i will attach the screenshot of mine.

Comment: Yes - I see something else. Added a screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Then click on you App Id in developer account 
App ID -> Edit -> you will get development and production ssl certificate mode.

Then upload your CSR file=> download aps_production.cer

Then use [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) link to create PEM file (Which used on server)

There is one simplepush.php file you can test from your mac cmd.

Hope this will help.

Comment: When I generate Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production) then Apple Push Services is created instead of Apple Production iOS Push Services

Comment: Yes you are doing right. Now right click on Apple Production iOS Push Services export you will get private key as a p12 file. use this for create certificate refer tutorial

Comment: I use Pusher application to test my push notifications certificate and it cannot read the p12 of the new Apple Push Services. I uses only the p12.